# How to make items unbreakable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a server for my friends and I would want items to have *infinite durability* on my server. How can I do that with command blocks?
Please include super high unbreaking enchantments! I also do not want mending books!

Comment: Do you want to make every item on the server unbreakable, or just `/give` some unbreakable items?

Comment: @AshtonTanner-Goulet only if the OP is asking for GIVING unbreakable items,  not for MAKING the existing ones indestructable.

Comment: Maybe having a command block that makes the activator's hand have the mending enchant? i do know that he can give indestructible items but to allow friends to do this without giving them access to commands would be easiest done like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a totally indestructible item use this:

```
/give @p minecraft:YOURITEM 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

To make the item *nearly* unbreakable use:

```
/give @p minecraft:YOURITEM 1 0 {ench:[{id:34,lvl:1000}]}
```

And to make it self-repairing use:

```
/give @p minecraft:YOURITEM 1 0 {ench:[{id:70,lvl:1}]}
```

(another option is using both enchants at once)

Or, if you want to make **all** items unbreakable, just give each player a ton of Mending books.

Comment: 1 --> yes, that works.  2 --> yes, that also works but i think the OP was looking for 1 but did not know it existed / was possible 3 --> not what the op was looking for, especially the last sentence i think.  giving / making mending books widly available is not really a soloution, i have put a possible idea up at the original question.

Comment: Is it blast-proof too? Because Im going to make a self destruct house

Answer (score 1):

You need to have cheats on but the closet you can come would be:

/enchant [player] [enchantment ID] [level]

For all enchantment names go to:

https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/enchantment_list_pc.php

Comment: actually there is a unbreakable data tag acoording to rudolf and it works i tested it